# Borderless window mode in Payday 2?

Tags: payday-2

I have a multi-monitor setup on the PC that I generally game on, as a result I usually run games either in EyeFinity mode (utilising all monitors as a single screen with the game across all of them) or more often, running games in "borderless window mode" so that I can freely move my mouse between screens and chat on the bridge, or whatever.

Payday 2 doesn't support borderless window mode - it has a bordered window mode and a fullscreen mode. Are there any configuration file changes I can make that will force a borderless window mode, or any external utilities I can use to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borderless Window Mode (Fullscreen Window Mode) is not available natively in Payday 2 as an option, you're only able to run the game in fullscreen mode or windowed mode (with a window border). [Numerous](http://steamcommunity.com/app/218620/discussions/0/864977025616833093/) [people](http://steamcommunity.com/app/218620/discussions/0/864976115225307830/) [have](http://steamcommunity.com/app/218620/discussions/0/864975632896677910/) [asked](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-2675769.html) for this feature on the Steam forums and Overkill forums but as of yet there hasn't been an official response in relation to this feature request.

As a workaround, you can use [Windowed Borderless Gaming](https://gc-modding.googlecode.com/files/WindowedBorderlessGaming_1.1.1.2.zip) but this has been reported to occasionally cause some minor issues with distorted text in game.

Answer (score 2):

[ShiftWindow](http://download.cnet.com/ShiftWindow/3000-2072_4-75899229.html) is my preferred way of dealing with games that don't have a native borderless window mode.

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about steam you can right click on payday 2 in your library and then select preferences. A window should come up and if you click set launch options and type in"-windowed" it should launch in windowed mode.